# How to mock the return value of messages.create() method from twilio-node using sinon js/loopback testlab?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, twilio, sinon

I'm trying to mock the return value of **messages.create()** method from **twilio-node** library.

Since the create method resides inside the interface called **messages**, i can't directly mock the return value of create method.

**My Unit test:**

```
import {
  createStubInstance,
  StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor,
} from '@loopback/testlab';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {Twilio} from '../../../../clients/whatsapp-sms-clients/twilio.whatsapp-sms-clients';
import twilio from 'twilio';

describe('Twilio client (UnitTest)', () => {
  let twilioMock: StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<twilio.Twilio>;
  let logger: StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<LoggingService>;
  let twilioClient: Twilio;

  beforeEach(() => {
    twilioMock = createStubInstance(twilio.Twilio);
    logger = createStubInstance(LoggingService);
    twilioClient = new Twilio(twilioMock, logger);
  });

  it('should create the message', async () => {
    twilioMock.stubs.messages.create.resolves({
      // mocked value
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not worked with `testlab`/`sinon` like this before, but I think I have an idea of what you need to do, if not the right syntax.

You'd need to stub the response to `twilioMock.messages` to return an object that has a `create` property that is a stubbed function that resolves to the result you want. Something like this might work, or at least set you on the right track:

```js
  it('should create the message', async () => {
    // Create stub for response to create method:
    const createStub = sinon.stub().resolves({
      // mocked value
    });
    // Stub the value "messages" to return an object that has a create property with the above stub:
    twilioMock.stubs.messages.value({ 
      create: createStub
    });

    // Rest of the test script
  });
```

**Edit**

OK, using `value` above didn't work. I tried again. This version strips out your custom Twilio wrapper from the example and just calls things directly on the Twilio client stub itself. Hopefully you can use this as inspiration to work it into your tests.

What I realised is that [`twilioClient.messages` is a getter](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/9d256ddf0c4ade609cae2de4babecafdb276ae08/lib/rest/Twilio.js#L773-L778) and is dynamically defined. So, I directly stubbed the result on the stub client.

```
import {
  createStubInstance,
  StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor,
} from "@loopback/testlab";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { Twilio } from "twilio";

describe("Twilio client (UnitTest)", () => {
  let twilioMock: StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<Twilio>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    twilioMock = createStubInstance(Twilio);
  });

  it("should create the message", async () => {
    const createStub = sinon.stub().resolves({
      sid: "SM1234567",
    });
    sinon.stub(twilioMock, "messages").get(() => ({
      create: createStub,
    }));
    const message = await twilioMock.messages.create({
      to: "blah",
      from: "blah",
      body: "hello",
    });
    expect(message.sid).toEqual("SM1234567");
  });
});
```

The above test passes for me in my setup.

Comment: Tried the above and getting error **TypeError: twilioMock.stubs.messages.value is not a function** @philnash

Comment: That's weird, I just spun up a project to test this and in VS Code TypeScript has no issue, but running the test does come up with the same error. I'll look into it.

Comment: OK, edited my answer with a new idea. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Awesome it is working as expected. Thank you so much @philnash.