# How to unit test twilio for programmable Video API in typescript?

Tags: typescript, twilio, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I'm using [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) package in my backend which uses loopback4 with Typescript.
I'm writing unit test cases using Mocha,Jest and sinon but facing following difficulties.

I'm having a twilio service which looks like this

```
export class TwilioService {
  twilioBaseUrl = 'https://video.twilio.com';
  twilioClient: TwilioClient;
  constructor(
    @inject(TwilioBindings.config) 
    private readonly twilioConfig: TwilioConfig,
    @repository(VideoChatSessionRepository)
    private readonly videoChatSessionRepository: VideoChatSessionRepository,
    @repository(SessionAttendeesRepository)
    private readonly sessionAttendeesRepository: SessionAttendeesRepository,
  ) {
    const {accountSid, apiSid, apiSecret, authToken} = twilioConfig;
    if (!(accountSid && apiSid && apiSecret && authToken)) {
      throw new HttpErrors.BadRequest(`Twilio API credentials are not set`);
    }
    this.twilioClient = twilio(twilioConfig.accountSid, twilioConfig.authToken);
  }

   async deleteArchive(archiveId: string): Promise<void> {
    const result = await this.twilioClient.video
      .recordings(archiveId)
      .remove((err, items) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new HttpErrors.ExpectationFailed(`Error deleting archive`);
        }
      });
    if (!result) {
      throw new HttpErrors.ExpectationFailed(`Error deleting archives`);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Now here for the method `deleteArchive(arciveId:string):Promise<void>`

I write the test cases as

```
  describe('deleteArchive', () => {
    it('delete the archive with given arhive id', async () => {
      const recordingContext = sinon.createStubInstance(RecordingContext);
      recordingContext.remove.resolves(true);
      sinon
        .stub(twilioService.twilioClient.video, 'recordings')
        .returns(recordingContext);

      const result = await twilioService.twilioClient.video
        .recordings(archiveId)
        .remove();
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(recordingContext.remove);
      
    });
  });
```

it gives me error that

```
 Error: The requested resource /Recordings/RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX was not 
  found
  at success (node_modules/twilio/lib/base/Version.js:113:15)
  at Promise_then_fulfilled (node_modules/q/q.js:766:44)
  at Promise_done_fulfilled (node_modules/q/q.js:835:31)
  at Fulfilled_dispatch [as dispatch] (node_modules/q/q.js:1229:9)
  at Pending_become_eachMessage_task (node_modules/q/q.js:1369:30)
  at RawTask.call (node_modules/asap/asap.js:40:19)
  at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

The actual issue that seems to me is that actual `recordings` method is called instead of my stubbed one, which throws the error.

So my question is
`twilioClient.video.recordings` returns an object which has a method `remove` how to deal with such scenario where we want to stub a method of an object which is also the result of stubbed method.

Comment: Does the [answer here help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69578326/28376)? It's not for this particular function call, but it addresses mocking this library.

Comment: @philnash didn't worked for me. I solved it using proxyquire

Comment: Ah, ok. It would help others if you write an answer to explain what you did!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I figured out is my stubbed function was not called. Instead it is the actual one which throws the error.

So I mocked the entire twilio library using proxyquire as follows:

```
  describe('deleteArchive', () => {
it('delete the archive with given arhive id', async () => {
  const removeStub = sinon.stub().resolves(true);
  const recordingStub = sinon.stub().returns({
    remove: removeStub,
  });

  const TwilioMockService = proxyquire(
    '../../../providers/twilio/twilio.service',
    {
      twilio: (accountSid: string, authToken: string) => {
        return {
          video: {
            recordings: recordingStub,
          },
        };
      },
    },
  ).TwilioService;
  const twilioMockServiceInstance = new TwilioMockService(
    twilioConfig,
    videoChatSessionRepo,
    sessionAttendeesRepo,
  );
  twilioProvider = new TwilioProvider(twilioMockServiceInstance);

  await twilioProvider.value().deleteArchive(archiveId);
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(removeStub);
});
});
```

PS: twilio provider is just a wrapper over TwilioService.
It just exposes the methods of twilioServie and nothing else.

It is required because of the lb4 architecture and nothing else